# Finding a value for corresponding string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to know how I can do the following without using an if formula in excel.

Let's say this is sheet 1 [Data]:

[image]

On sheet 2, I want the numerical values like this:

[image]

In this case an if statement would not be too complicated, but I need to do this with 20 values and 30 rows with 10 columns of data.

Is this possible or am I in for the mother of all if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a VLOOKUP function.

On Sheet2, put this formula in cell A1 and copy/paste into the other cells.

```
=VLOOKUP(Data!A1,Data!$G$1:$H$3,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
=MATCH(Sheet2!A1,{"Bad","Caution","Good"})
```

And fill all the area.